# Call static method with Azure WebJobs

Tags: c#, multithreading, azure, thread-safety, azure-webjobs

I have created a dll which consist of static class.I referred them in my web-jobs(webjob1,webjob2,etc..) created and deployed in azure.

Each web-job may access a method simultaneously.As we are using static class,  it will create single memory in heap. Every web-job contains the reference value of that static class. My Question is, will it create any problem?

As per my understanding, C# works in a synchronous fashion. Thus, each web-job will wait in a queue to access the functions of static class. So any change made for the variables of that static class will reflect on other webjobs.Since static class have stand alone memory.

If my assumption is right, why should we keep such static helper class instead of normal one which we can instantiate and use it.

I am creating static class like this inorder to get some details from my db.

```
public static class StaticHelper
    {
        public static string GetValue()
        {
            using(IDBContext _DbContext = new sampleDBContext())
            {

             }

            //Acessing values through this context
        }
    }
```

Comment: Really depends on what you try to achieve. C# also have async/await pattern. It will be easier if you can post your code here. Cheers.

Comment: @Thomas Have Updated...

Comment: Webjobs won't wait to access your static method. They are going to call it concurrently.

Comment: Can you answer some clarifying questions to help us out? 
1. Are you just running a console app as a webjob or are you using the SDK?  
2. What about multiple instances of your website - are you ever going to scale out?

Comment: @JasonHaley 1.we are using sdk for webjobs. 2.and about multiple instances,yes we are creating multiple instances of website under same subscription in azure.

Comment: Are you using any triggers, like the queue trigger?

Comment: @JasonHaley No i am not using any triggers.

Comment: I started answering but have a couple more questions: 1. by "webjob1, webjob2" you mean that you have multiple console applications, correct? 2. are you running the webjobs as single instance or multiple instance?

Comment: @JasonHaley I am running  two webjobs like: webjob1,webjob2 under same website(web app in azure) which means single instance of website.so As per my understanding static class will create its memory in wesite level.so one webjob will get affected by another webjob's action on that static class.is it correct?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand it correctly, you have multiple webjobs that have the same dependency on a dll.  You have multiple instances of that website and use use the SDK but not the queue trigger.

Each webjob will be running as its own process and each instance of the website may have other instances of those webjobs (depends on if you have set single instance or multiple instance).

"Each web-job may access a method simultaneously" - yes but they will be in different processes so you will be safe in that case.

If that answers your question, more detail is really in learning about how .net and multiple processes handle static logic (not really webjobs specific).  I would start with Jeffry Richter to learn that detail.

Comment: I need some more clarifications from your answer...since you are mentioning webjobs working as a process each webjobs will create its own memory and have its own static class instance(refers static class memory is allocated under process memory(webjob memory)).so it will be thred safe.is it right?

Comment: By looking at the Kudu code it looks to me as though the webjob gets a brand new cmd.exe process.  The webjob directory gets set to the ProcessStartInfo, wrapped and then started.  Which leads me to believe there isn't shared memory between the site and webjobs.  ProcessWrapper.cs wraps the underlying Process and gets started in this class: https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Core/Infrastructure/ProcessWrapper.cs.  The Process is created in the Executable.cs class method CreateProcess() https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/blob/master/Kudu.Core/Infrastructure/Executable.cs

Comment: Thank you so much...you are right each webjobs are running in different process so it will be thread safe.

Answer (score 0):

Each WebJob runs in its own process, which is distinct from the WebApp's process (w3wp). So they will each have their own copy of static variables.

[IS Azure Webjobs have its own memory allocation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38121776/is-azure-webjobs-have-its-own-memory-allocation)